# Safari proxy bypass for IPv6

Tags: macos, mac, proxy, safari, ipv6

I'm a first-time n00b on Mac (but have been doing computers since before PC's).
This Mac has 2 VLANs, vlan0 in IPv4, vlan1 in IPv6.
Safari can surf via IPv4 squid proxy OK.
Safari can surf via IPv6 natively, if I switch off the proxy.
How do I set up the Settings -> Network -> Interface -> Advanced -> Proxies to "bypass" IPv6?

Current Settings include variations along the lines of ...

```
"*.local, 10.0.0.0/8, 192.168.0.0/16, 172.16.0.0/12 , ::, ipv6 "
```

but don't work as expected.

I want Safari to go out on its own with IPv6, not crash at the proxy with "malformed URL"

Thanks,
//rhi

Comment: [Mac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macintosh) is not [MAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address).